# Firebase: Need to prove authorization to an API

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a custom REST API that takes in user/password and I see how I can use that API to generate and return a custom token that the Firebase SDK running on my mobile app would use to authenticate to the Firebase server.

Here is what I need help with. I now want a third system, another REST API, that returns private but generic data, but knows nothing about users, to be sent some kind of token that proves its a logged in user originating in my mobile app.

How would I handle that? Is there a way to get a token from the logged in user on my mobile app, pass it to my api and validate it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to [verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) using the Admin SDKs. For instance, if I have a Firebase ID token I can write code like:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(decodedToken => {
    let uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
  });
```